# Alternative to OpenSSL in Indy SMTP component

Tags: multithreading, delphi, openssl, indy

When running component SMTP and POP too, am getting AV in OpenSSL library, as I found several complaints about this on Google, I would use an alternative to OpenSSL.

I'm sure that the component of Indy has no error because Remy Lebeau is the master, but I need an alternative. Will I have to leave this beautiful work which is the component of Indy?

Comment: Can you use English ?

Comment: Yes, Google translate because I'm lazy today

Comment: thank for edit the title, I think I copy the wrong text language... sorry...

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you using and where did you dowload it from?

Comment: the version is last one "openssl-1.0.1e" and I dont know where I donwload, does it matter?

Comment: Did you try from [OpenSSL's own website](http://www.openssl.org)? Did you try from [Indy's Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com)?

Comment: I don´t know where I download, but I know that was not from the OpenSSL Official site, because the only thing I found in OpenSSL site was the source not the binarys for windows OS. Thanks, Ill try the Fulgans Dll Mirror thank you

Comment: I download the openssl from Indy's Fulgan mirror, and the AV seens to disapear. I´ll stay for a while to close this question because, im not sure, that AV realy desapear. But I got a nice feed back now. Gambit!

Comment: Nice nice nice... the AV realy desapear. Thank you Remy! You are the one. Can send me your picture so I can hang on my bedroom wall?

Comment: OpenSSL's website has a link to pre-made Windows binaries.  Go to the "Related | Binaries" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy's OpenSSL usage is fairly well tested, and used by many people without problem.  If you are having AVs with it, I would suspect a bug in your own code before I suspect a problem with Indy. That's not to say that Indy is perfect and bug free, of course.  So if you suspect an Indy or OpenSSL bug, you need to provide specific details, code snippets, etc to verify it, otherwise no one can help you. If you have seen other complaints, provide links to them.

As for your actual question, there are third-party alternatives available, such as [EldoS SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/), which includes an `TIdIOHandler` SSL implementation for Indy.

Comment: I know Remy, the Indy was heavily tested, 
I love the indy components. 
However, I suspect that error is lack of memory, which does not properly warn the incident, 
and the problem of lack of memory, it sends an AV. 

This time, I'm sure this code perfect. 
I can send you the source code if you could read it, 
not only posted here because it is too long.

The error only really happens when I create a 99 threads at the same time, 
and this error does not always happen, and when it does, occur inside the OpenSSL dlls.

Comment: The AV seens to desapear. So I Don't need to change the open SSL.